# Using web.config to block content based on IP address

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

Is it possible to block a specific content based on IP address in web.config, for IIS8?

For example:

```
<location path="somesite">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="redirect/somesite" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Would it be possible to block a specific entry as above based on IP address, and redirect to a 404 error page of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this wont be possible via web.config, though I may be wrong also. However I have successfully used global.asax for doing these kind of nasty stuff. Mind it that you cant be 100% sure about the Ip address, they can be spoofed, so you donowanna use it for security crital task.

Step 1. add a global.asax if you dont have

step 2. create a method as

```
      protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
      }
```

Application_BeginRequest is fired every time a resourse is requested.

Step 3. In this method verify IP address and redirect them where ever you want.

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [An IP Address Blocking HttpModule for ASP.NET in 9 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnIPAddressBlockingHttpModuleForASPNETIn9Minutes.aspx). It does what you want (404) but keeps ips in a separated file. That makes more sense because changing the web.config every time will lead to an application restart.

And if you want to block IPs on IIS level, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889%28WS.10%29.aspx